# iPhone App Login Screen + MySQL Database

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, validation, authentication

I'm developing an application where I have a login screen. I'd like to have the user credentials stored in a MySQL database.

I have a database created with id, username and password fields. I can run a select statement and the console shows the results.

I was wondering how would I go about making a login screen with username and password validation using the MySQL database I have created. I have read that this must be done by writing a PHP script and have the iPhone app to reference this in order to access the database, however my PHP knowledge is limited.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: instead using sqlite will  be the best thing i suggest..

Comment: Hi. thanks for the response. Yes, we looked into that originally and I think it would be a far easier solution however I have read that this can only be used locally? I could be wrong on this. Our aim is to have the database on a server which the app would access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// PHP PART
create a PHP file which takes username and password as parameters.

(For better security USE ENCRYPTION AND DECRYPTION)

In that PHP file check whether the username and password are authorized or not and in response give proper message)

// iPhone Part

PAss the username and password with the PHP URL

Fetch the response and decide through response whether its authorized or not..